# String index out of bound exception when finding substring in java

Tags: java, string, substring

In this code i am trying to find the character(only 1) before  and after str1 string in str string using java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "abcXY123XYijk";
    String str1 = "XY";

    int[] arr = new int[str.length()];

    for(int i=0;i<str.length()-2;i++){
        if( "XY".equals(str.substring(i,2))){

            int index=str.indexOf("XY");

            System.out.println(String.valueOf(str.charAt(index-1))+String.valueOf(str.charAt(index+str1.length())));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: public class String11 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str="abcXY123XYijk";
        String str1="XY";
        
        int[] arr=new int[str.length()];
        
  
        for(int i=0;i<str.length()-2;i++){
        if( "XY".equals(str.substring(i,2))){
               
               int index=str.indexOf("XY");
               System.out.println(String.valueOf(str.charAt(index-1))+String.valueOf(str.charAt(index+str1.length())));
           }
   }
    }
}

Comment: Please give the exact error when getting an exception ;)

Comment: Please describe what your goal is and what error messages you are getting exactly.

Comment: Are you expecting output like below:
c1
3i

Comment: output expected is "c1 3i"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact error is `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 3, end 2, length 13`, it tells you that you try to get a substring that starts at index `3` and ends at index `2`, the second parameter is not the length, but the end, so use `i+2`

Also `str.indexOf("XY")` returns the first index, so you'll always get the same result, so use `str.indexOf("XY", i)` the second parameter is the index in the string from which to begin the search

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.length() - 3; i++) {
    if ("XY".equals(str.substring(i, i + 2))) {
        int index = str.indexOf("XY", i);
        System.out.println("" + str.charAt(index-1) + str.charAt(index + str1.length()));
    }
}

// Outputs
c1
3i
```

---

### *Now better*

As you check that between `i,i+2` you have **XY**, use the index `i` to do get the previous and next chars, no need to find the index again, also replace the `2` by the length of the variable that stores `XY`

```
String find = "XY";
for (int i = 0; i < str.length() - 3; i++) {
    if (find.equals(str.substring(i, i + find.length()))) {
        System.out.println("" + str.charAt(i - 1) + str.charAt(i + find.length()));
    }
}
```

Comment: **Thank you!** very much